# Query between dates based on Concat year, month and day fields

Tags: mysql, etl

After I pass an `ETL` to a database system I have a time dimension called "dim_time", the table is composed out of many fields like:

```
- id
- year
- month
- day
- hour
- week
- day_of_week
```

I am trying to get a range of ids from that table, querying it between 2 dates, after many tests I thought the best option was `concat` the fields and ask `<=` and `>=`, this is the query:

```
SELECT `DimTime`.`id` FROM `dim_time` AS `DimTime` 
  WHERE ((CONCAT(`DimTime`.`year`, "-", `DimTime`.`month`, "-", `DimTime`.`day`, " 00:00:00") >= CONCAT(2013, "-", 10, "-", 9, " 00:00:00")) 
  AND (CONCAT(`DimTime`.`year`, "-", `DimTime`.`month`, "-", `DimTime`.`day`, " 00:00:00") <= CONCAT(2013, "-", 11, "-", 13, " 00:00:00"))) 
  ORDER BY `DimTime`.`year` DESC, `DimTime`.`quarter` DESC, `DimTime`.`month` DESC, `DimTime`.`week` DESC, `DimTime`.`day` DESC, `DimTime`.`hour` DESC
```

This query returns ids of rows that are day 9 of month 10, and all days on month 11, day 1 to day 13 (limit in query).

Why the rest of days of month 10 are not in result? Days between 10 - 31.

I don't know if I miss something or if `MySQL` can't treat a `concat` as date comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works when you have a date like `2013-11-13`, but you have to cast it to date when your concatenated date is something like `2013-1-2`, because a valid date would be `2013-01-02`.

Anyway, your best bet is to add a column with the full date to your dim_time table. Especially because even if you get this to work, your query couldn't use an index. You'd have to write it like

```
WHERE `DimTime`.`year` >= 2013
AND `DimTime`.`month` >= 10
...
```

Then an index can be used. So, make your life easy, add a full date column to your table.

Comment: I think in add the full date to the table, but the developers chief of that project, dont want it :S. Thats why i loosing me time with that query... How i can cast the concat to a date? Ok, STR_TO_DATE

Comment: You can do so by doing `CAST(CONCAT(...) AS DATE) AS column_name`. Would be interesting, why the chief of the project doesn't want that. I'm working several years in exactly this business, working on ETLs all day, and I can just facepalm when hearing this.